Multiple Regex Validation on single Sitecore Form Field
I need to add 2 regex validation on single input field with 2 different messages.
First One should check if number starting from 1 or 3, the Second one should check for format like 1-12345-123-12.
How to achieve this?
I get an error message validation types must be unique when I try to add the 2 validation types to the field.

Seems like this should be doable in a single regex?

Why try to do this in 2 validators? Just use a single validator like this:
^[13]-\d{5}-\d{3}-\d{2}$

Then make sure your error message covers both scenarios:

Please make sure the value starts with either 1 or 3 and follows the format: 1-12345-123-12.

This keeps it simple and you don't have the problem you are getting.

2 different messages are needed, so one validation alone will not work.

It is not possible as you have seen to have 2 different messages.

You can create a new Regex Validators for the fields, and then add the validator in the Validators fields of the Input Item.
To create a Regex Validator, navigate to /sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Validations and duplicate the Phone Number Validator (As it is a Regex Validator) and add the required regex in the Parameters field using {"regularExpression":"[The Expression]"} syntax. In the Message field, you can add the message you want to show when the validator returns false. In the Message field, you can get the field name using the format placeholder like, {0} field is empty, here {0} will get replaced by the Field Name.

E.g., I have created a test form and added a single-line Input field. Now in the content Editor, when selecting the field Item, we can see the Validations Multi-List Field, in which we can select all the validators that we want to include.

I think this will resolve your issue.

You are getting this issue since Sitecore Form uses unobtrusive client library for  validation. It requires validation type name should be unique.
In order to resolve this issue, you will need to extend the RegularExpressionValidation class as below, to add different types when multiple regular expression validations are added to the field.

Extend the regular expression validation class as below, to take the validation item name as the validation type.

using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Validation;
using SitecoreCustomExtensions.ValidationRegexRule;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class CustomRegexValidation : RegularExpressionValidation
{
   public CustomRegexValidation(ValidationDataModel validationItem)
   : base(validationItem)
   {
   }

   public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> ClientValidationRules
   {
      get
      {
         CustomRegexValidation expressionValidation = this;
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(expressionValidation.RegularExpression))
         {
           Regex regex = new Regex(expressionValidation.RegularExpression, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled);
           yield return (ModelClientValidationRule)new CustomModelClientValidationRegexRule(expressionValidation.FormatMessage((object)expressionValidation.Title), regex.ToString(), this.ValidationItem.DisplayName.Replace(" ", "").ToLower());
          }
       }
    }
}

Note: The validation item name is the name of the validator item created inside Sitecore. Using that name, the validation type is added.

Create the validation rule as below to take the validation item name as the type. This class is being reference in above class to create a validation rule.

using System.Web.Mvc;

public class CustomModelClientValidationRegexRule : ModelClientValidationRule
{
   public CustomModelClientValidationRegexRule(string errorMessage, string pattern, string validationType)
   {
      this.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
      this.ValidationType = validationType;
      this.ValidationParameters.Add(nameof(pattern), (object)pattern);
    }
}


Once the above changes are done, you can reference above class inside the field validator created inside Sitecore.



In the last step, you need to register above validators created with the validation item name, inside the JavaScript as below in order for the validation to work on the frontend.

jQuery.validator.addMethod("{{ValidationItemName}}", function (value, element, params) {
        var match;
        if (this.optional(element)) {
            return true;
        }

        match = new RegExp(params).exec(value);
        return (match && (match.index === 0) && (match[0].length === value.length));
});

jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("{{ValidationItemName}}", "pattern");

{{ValidationItemName}} in the above code, is the name of the validation item created in Sitecore to be entered in lowercase format. Add this method for each of the regex validation item created in Sitecore.
This will add mutiple regex pattern on the field as below.

Using above changes, you can add multiple regex expression in the field validator and provide different messages for each use case.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.

To apply two validation rules on a single input field in Sitecore Forms, follow these steps:
Step 1: Create custom validations according to your requirements at /sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Validations. For your case, create two validation rules:
Validation 1: For checking if the input is 1 or 3, use the following regex:

  for 1 or 3 regex -- {"regularExpression":"^(1|3)"}

Validation 2: For format checking, use the following regex:

 for format check  -- {"regularExpression":"^\d-\d{5}-\d{3}-\d{2}$"}

Step 2: Add these validations to the input field in the Sitecore Forms editor and save your changes. This will apply both validations to a single field.

Note: It's generally easier to perform these steps in the Content Editor rather than the Forms Editor.
Hope this helps!

Adding both Validation on single filed of same type regular expression give error validation types must be unique.

At what point does this message appear—while saving or adding data to the original form input?

on front end when u view the page on which form is added
